# Get-NetAdapterBinding cmdlet not available in windows powershell 5.0 window-7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I want to bind a network adapter using command `Enable-NetAdapterBinding` via powershell. I am working on window-7 64bit (sp 1) which have powershell 4.0. When i failed to execute this command than i upgrade powershell with 5.0. In 5.0 also not getting any `NetAdapterBinding` cmdlet.

*What i exactly want to run in powershell.*

```
PS C:\> Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "MyAdapter" -DisplayName "ipfw+dummynet"
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329513/automate-installation-of-dummynet-driver-using-powershell) is steps i'm following.

Please help if any one coming through this problem.

Note: `1. Open powershell in administrator mode`. `Driver have kernel mode code sighing certificate`.

Comment: Maybe, it applies to Windows 8 and higher!

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui You are right. Is there any way i can achieve this task in windows-7. What if i update powershell in windows-7 matching with windows-8? Is it OS specific or package specific?

Comment: I tried it before, and installed all necessary updates on Windows 7 SP1 including .NET 4.5 but no way, it's OS specific